# Display WEBP image on android from URL

Tags: java, android, webp

I'm trying to get and display a WEBP icon from Google PlayStore, like this one :
http://lh5.ggpht.com/YK0as9_ZRmSK6PBkSwRVQ62F5cBMq7gYMLfZ2nk30QjEVK6taYMPMKzh0eswMkBMhw=w170-rw

I tried using directly the data and decoding it with BitmapFactory (works sometimes ...), I also tried with the libwebp but when I test the data with the "WebPGetInfo" function it returns 0 (wich means the datas are not webp image ...)

Here is the code I use with libwebp:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(src).openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
                   "image/webp");
            connection.connect();

          //Send request
              DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                          connection.getOutputStream ());
              wr.writeBytes ("");
              wr.flush ();
              wr.close ();

              //Get Response    
              BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
            while(true) {
                String n = rd.readLine();
                if(n == null)break;
                baos.write(n.getBytes(), 0, n.getBytes().length);
                baos.write('\n');
            }

            byte data[] = baos.toByteArray();
                    // From the lib's exemple 
            int[] width = new int[] { 0 };
            int[] height = new int[] { 0 };

            int test = libwebp.WebPGetInfo(data, data.length, width, height); // test = 0 ! ! !

            byte[] decoded = libwebp.WebPDecodeARGB(data, data.length, width, height); 

            int[] pixels = new int[decoded.length / 4];
            ByteBuffer.wrap(decoded).asIntBuffer().get(pixels);

            bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(pixels, width[0], height[0], Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bmp;

    }
```

Thx for your help.

EDIT : After multiple changes I now have a NoClassDefFoundError when using libwebp ...

Comment: I will not post this as an answer because I assume you will want to solve the problem in app. I have had other image issues where the solution was to have a simple proxy web service convert, cache and send images in our desired format.

Comment: I'll try that, but since the debug is telling me that the datas I got from the URL are bad maybe it will be the same.

Comment: Actually, I will eventually manually convert them and get them from a database I have ... but that is the solution if I'm about to break my computer from despaire ^^

Comment: http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html